# How to add update function to plugin without adding it to https://wordpress.org/plugins/

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, updates

Anyone have an idea or could point me to a tutorial/guide. All help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are scripts available which can do the job for you. As per my understanding, you will have to host your plugin updates on a remote location so that the update checker can access that and do the necessary job.

You can take a look at [this script](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/) which seems to be very useful as per the comments.

You can also find examples on that page which you can check with. This is also available on [github](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker).